# Why do My Python Script Work on Window Script Host Run Method, But NOT Exec Method

Tags: python, vba, shell, windows-scripting

I have a simple Python script ("hi.py") as below

```
import time

print("HI")
time.sleep(5)
```

I am using Excel VBA to call ""hi.py" by `Windows Script Host's Run Method` (code as below).  It works.

```
sub testRun()
    Dim wsh As Object
    Dim a As Variant

    Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    a = wsh.run("C:\tmpFolder\pyProject\myProject\hi.py", 1, True)
End Sub
```

But if I use `Windows Script Host's Exec Method` rather than `Run Method`, my computer say `hi.py is not a valid win 32 application`.

```
Sub testExec()
    Dim wsh As Object, oexec As Object

    Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set oexec = wsh.exec("C:\tmpFolder\pyProject\myProject\hi.py")
End Sub
```

How can I run my python script with `Windows Script Host Exec Method`?
Thank you very much.

Comment: `wsh.exec` requires a binary executable file. A Python file is neither binary nor executable. There exist methods to compile as Python file into an EXE. Use Google to find them.

Comment: @DYZ thanks.  I will Google something like `py2exe`.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45410316/is-there-a-way-to-call-a-python-code-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Method `exec()` needs a String that can be passed to the command line. Try `python C:\tmpFolder\pyProject\myProject\hi.py` or `python3 C:\tmpFolder\pyProject\myProject\hi.py`, just like you would type it in `CMD.exe`

[Link to the Syntax at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: I try `python C:\tmpFolder\pyProject\myProject\hi.py`, but don't see `HI` on the python window.